# Oracle 11G, Move indexes from one datafile to another

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle 11G DB installed on Windows Server 2008 SP2 64bit OS. Below is some data files usage statistics:

[image]

As you can see, there are two files: `index01.dbf` and `index02.dbf` belong to the same tablespace `Indx` (which is used for storing indexes of all the schemas). Since `index01.dbf` has much free space, I am going to find the exact indexes built on `index02.dbf` and move them to `index01.dbf` and let `index02.dbf` become empty, then remove `index02.dbf` from db. Could anyone give me some instruction or detailed approach?

Comment: You can't move data between data files only between _tablespaces_.

Comment: You can't move data between data files, objects like index, tables can moved only between tablespaces. but why you want to move index from one data file to other data file.

Comment: index01.dbf is 32G, its unused space is 10G, index02.dbf is 6G and it has 3G free space. I want to move indexes on index02.dbf to index01.dbf, then drop empty index02.dbf.

Comment: Create a new tablespace, move the indexes to the new tablespace and then either drop the old tablespace or clean it up and move the indexes back.

Comment: Why do you assume that a single index exists in a single data file?  Normally, you'd expect that indexes in the same tablespace would likely have extents in each of the data files.

Answer (score 3):

You move tables, not indexes. You **rebuild** indexes.

However, when you rebuild indexes, you can specify a tablespace, not a datafile, so no difference in that aspect.

Since you have to rebuild the indexes anyway, instead of rebuilding them immediately (and not having control in which datafile the new extents will be placed), you can just simply make the indexes `UNUSABLE` first. That drops their segments, and when the second datafile becomes empty (you can check this in `DBA_EXTENTS`), drop the second datafile, and finally rebuild the indexes.

First, make the indexes unusable:

```
alter index user.index1 unusable;
...
```

Check the extents in your second datafile:

```
select * from dba_extents where file_id = 7;
```

7 is the id of your file on your screenshot. When all the extents are gone (the above query does not return anything), drop the datafile:

```
alter tablespace indx drop datafile 7;
```

And finally rebuild the indexes:

```
alter index user.index1 rebuild;
...
```

You could "optimize" the above with making only those indexes unusable, that have extents in the second datafile by checking `DBA_EXTENTS` for different `segment_name` values, though I would not put too much effort in that, because that is very unlikely for a tablespace having multiple datafiles to have extents only in 1 datafile + the total size of your indexes is only 23 GB at most, even if you rebuild all of them, it should not take long.